# confusion of all the W3C specifications and implementations of different browsers

Tags: android, ios, html, touch, w3c

I got really confused of all the W3C specifications and implementations of different browsers.
I have a list questions:

1. I found this page from W3C's website: http://dvcs.w3.org/hg/webevents/raw-file/tip/touchevents.html

And I found this page from apple's website: http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/UserExperience/Reference/TouchEventClassReference/TouchEvent/TouchEvent.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009358

They are talking basically the same thing.

So my question is : did apple published all the multi-touch apis first then W3C followed apple to make all the specifications? or did W3C published the specifications first then apple followed the specifications to make a new version of Safari?

2.Is the Touch Events Specification a part of HTML5 specification?

3.If I write a web page that uses multi-touch to interact with users, can the users be able to use this web page in IPad, Android devices and Windows Phone 7(Mango)?
Or do I have to write different code for each different platform?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Touch Events Specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-touch-events-20110505/) is based on events cloned from Apple Safari's implementation, although it adds significantly to it. It is not technically part of HTML5. The other platforms have also copied Safari's touch events. It should be possible to write code to the original Apple Safari reference documentation and have it work on iPad and Android. I don't know about Windows Phone 7 (Mango).

Comment: Thanks for replying, I have a follow-up question: if Touch Events Specification is not a part of HTML5 specification, then what's its position in this whole system?

Comment: It is being drafted and edited by a separate working group within the W3C than the HTML working group, a new group called the Web Events Working Group. The draft is considered an extension to the DOM Level 2 Events specification. As a practical matter, however, it is one of the many APIs often referred to as "HTML5" simply because "HTML5" has become a loose marketing term used for all sorts of new exciting web technologies currently being introduced.